# Are there any shower facilities at Heathrow Airport?

Tags: airports, lhr, hygiene

I have a very early flight in Heathrow airport Terminal 4 and was wondering if there are any shower facilities at Heathrow airport and how much they will cost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [Plaza Premium Lounge](https://www.plazapremiumlounge.com/en-uk/find/americas-europe/united-kingdom/london/london-heathrow-airport/plaza-premium-lounge-departures-terminal-4) in Terminal 4 departures (Located between Gate No.1A and 1B). Using the form on the left, booking the lounge for a 30-minute shower is £14.58 (US $18).

Note: The lounge opens at 5 am

The [Heathrow Airport Website](https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/toilets-and-showers) also states lounge facilities with showers in other terminals:

> Showers are available in the following lounges (fees apply)
>
> - Terminal 2: Plaza Premium Lounge (arrivals - public area)
> - Terminal 2: Plaza Premium Lounge (departure lounge - passenger area)
> - Terminal 3: Plaza Premium Lounge (arrivals - public area)
> - Terminal 3: No. 1 Traveller Lounge (departure lounge - passenger area)
> - Terminal 3: Regus Express Business Lounge (check-in - public area)
> - Terminal 4: Plaza Premium Lounge (departure lounge - passenger area)
> - Terminal 4: Plaza Premium Lounge (arrivals - public area)
> - Terminal 5: Aspire Lounge and Spa (departure lounge - passenger area)